# Generating braintree token in nested form Ruby on Rails 4.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, braintree

I need to generate a braintree client Token on my rails Orders form to create a DROPIN UI form. Usually, this can be easily done by calling,   Braintree::ClientToken.generate on the new action of the OrdersController so that every time a new orders form is created, a token is generated.
  def new 
       Braintree::ClientToken.generate
  end

However, my problem is that my Orders form is a partial that I render as a nested form on my listing show page. This means I only have a create action on my OrdersController and no new action and thus calling   Braintree::ClientToken.generate on the create action wont work because the token has to be sent to the client side javascript for the dropin to work before the form is created. How can i generate the token on my nested Orders form without a new action?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If just a single `ClientToken` is enough for all your nested forms then you can generate a new `Braintree::ClientToken` in the master action (e.g. the show action). The template of this action (e.g. the `show.html.erb` file), when rendering the nested partials (the order forms), can hand the token over to the partials as a local variable. This way you can easily distribute the same token to all your nested forms.

Comment: I thought about that but rails will look for the merchant_id configuration on the listingsController show action and this along with other braintree logic has to be set on the OrdersController, but thanks for trying to help

Comment: I think the only way to get the token in this situation is to use ajax.